# "Open Link Behind Mail" in Mail.app not working

Tags: macos, mail.app

When on my Mac I right click on a link in mail and select "Open Link Behind Mail" nothing happens.

I tried opening Console and seeing if there was an error message when I did it again, but I didn't notice anything new. (I looked in "SYSTEM LOG QUERIES > All Messages")

This was working a few months ago. I am using Mail 8.2 (2070.6) and OS X 10.10.2 (14C109)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google tells me it's a known bug.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/27198644#27198644

Workaround is to  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>  Click.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm having the same issue after upgrading to 10.10.2 (Yosemite) a couple days ago.  COMMAND-CLICK is another work-around as well.